# What is more efficient for card recognition? Text and small image or image of the entire card?

Tags: tensorflow, ocr, image-recognition, tf.keras, text-recognition

I want to create a Keras/TF model to recognise [Magic the Gathering Cards](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?multiverseid=420769&type=card).
The cards could be in different languages. Does it make more sense to recognise the card name on top and the [edition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPXdB.png) of the card, or just the artwork and edition? What is more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

Or try HMS scan kit for card recognition.
HMS Core Scan Kit supports most standard formats, providing long range detetction and improving the succcess rate of code scanning.

[image]

For more information, you can visit https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topicview?tid=0201236478929600089&fid=0101187876626530001

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do both. Use a set of masks for the artwork, edition and extract image features and use text extraction and text features. Your pipeline would be something like:

```
image --> artwkmask1 | --> artwork_feat_xtract --> [...] : artwork_feat_vec
      |   artwkmask2 |
      |   ...        |
      |   artwkmaskn |
      |
      +-> edtnmask1  | --> edition_feat_xtract --> [...] : edition_feat_vec
      |   edtnmask2  |
      |   ...        |
      |   edtnmaskm  |
      |    
      +-> txtmask1   | --> txt_feat_xtract ------> [...] : text_feat_vec 
          txtmask2   |
          ...        |
          txtmaskk   |
```

You can then combine the three feature vectors into one wide vector and then use them for classification.